# how to decompose a string?

Tags: java, string, split

let's say I have this string

```
String myString="  102   3  4     93  3";
```

I need to be able to access each integer in my string, but there is an unpredictable number of space characters that separates each integer. I'd want to end up with something like this

```
stuff[0]=102

stuff[1]=3

stuff[2]=4

stuff[3]=93

stuff[4]=3
```

Comment: `myString.split("\\s+");` does the splitting - but do you want Strings or ints at the end of it?  If it's the latter, then you'll need to loop through and do some parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `trim()` to delete trailing and leading spaces. Then you can use `split(regex)`:

```
String[] parts = myString.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Here we are using:

```
\\s   : Match any whitespace character
+    : Repeat one or more times
```

If you want `int` elements, you can use the `Integer.parseInt()` method:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
```

Comment: that answers it for now, thanks friend.

Answer (score 1):

Now that [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) is out, here's one solution to get an int array from your original String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString="  102   3  4     93  3";
    int[] arr = Arrays.stream(myString.trim().split("\\s+"))
                      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                      .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Output:

```
[102, 3, 4, 93, 3]
```